# How can I force Aurelia updating the DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom, aurelia

[image: Pentomino Puzzle]

I'm rebuilding this pentomino blocks puzzle in Aurelia (Angular version is here: http://www.ashware.nl/pentomino) because I could not achieve the effect I wanted in Angular. The puzzle game is working fine, but the auto solver - a service that's computing all the possible solutions for the puzzle (there are many) is so busy that Aurelia does not update the DOM.

The service I'm building (solver-service.js) mainly consists of a function that tries to fit a block (in all it's possible positions) on the board. When it succeeds it calls itself recursively to fit the next block and it uses backtracking when it gets stuck.
I tried several methods to reflect the model changes by the solver in the view, the latest being 'signal' to trigger value converters for the positioning and orientation of the puzzle blocks (pentominoes).

I tried micro-tasks to reflect the changes during the life cycle of aurelia, requestAnimationFrame() and promises to do the next step in the .then() part, but that makes the process asynchronous which breaks the backtracking mechanism here.
It might be possible that the fact that I'm using a double (nested) repeat.for to render the blocks is the culprit.

When I interrupt the execution in the inspector, Aurelia does update the view, but only the first level of the repeat.for, so the positions are updated, but not the orientation / rotation of the blocks, which are reflected by the second level.

Code can be viewed here: https://github.com/Esger/Pentominos2/tree/feature/solver

So what is the best way to let Aurelia update the view all the time during heavy computation? - I want to show the solving process continuously.

Comment: Can you provide a gist with a small example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Ok, I put app here: http://www.ashware.nl/pentomino2

Comment: When you run it, open the inspector set a break point in line 94 in solver-service.js (this.findNextFit(...)), then choose 'shuffle' from the game menu (this clears the board), then choose 'spoiler' from the game menu. In the console you can see then what the solver has done so far. But the view does not correspond to that. When you remove the breakpoint and let it run, the view won't be updated at all.
Sorry I don't know how to make a small example of this. :(

Comment: This has nothing to do with Aurelia. The problem is that Javascript is single threaded. Your solver-service needs to relinquish control at regular intervals for the UI to be updated – yes, making it asynchronous.

See if you can break up your solver algorithm into smaller pieces and execute them with setTimeout. Hopefully you can prevent the backtracking mechanism from breaking by using function closure to keep the context.

Comment: @JeffG I'm sure that when I'd build this in Vanilla js, I could call a function to update the Dom when I need to. Thereafter, a recursion / backtracking step folks

Comment: @JeffG ...folllows. No asynchronicity. Aurelia has a life cycle though, in which it does data binding and view updating and more, so I seem to have no control over the exact point that I want the view to be updated. I change the view-model and Aurelia takes care of the view updating. My function seems to be too busy for Aurelia to do the view updating.

Comment: @JeffG But thanks for your answer, I'll try to work out your suggestion!

Comment: This really is just how Javascript works. It is not easy to do long calculations and have the results shown as you go. You must do asynchronous coding. Another option would be to offload the calculations to a server and have your javascript client poll to get the current results as they are calculated. Good luck. I hope you get this to work!

Comment: @JeffG I'm digging into web workers to put my solver-service in a separate thread.

Comment: Web workers will probably your best option. Sorry I forgot to mention that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web workers did the trick! :) I put the solver service in a web worker, a separate thread, so Aurelia isn't blocked by the heavy computing of it anymore.
The worker sends data to the main thread from time to time or when it has found a solution. Perfect!

One problem abides: Aurelia does update the view with the positions of the blocks found by the worker, but only when I click or try to scroll the page - I have to keep doing that in order to see updates continuously.

So clicking and scrolling the page triggers Aurelia to update the view. It would be nicer if it could do that by itself. Thanks @jeffG for the direction.